# How to resize a picture from byte array?

Tags: image, winforms, datagridview, arrays

I have a picture in type `byte[]`. I set this picture in a datagridview cell. I can see it now, but it's too big. I would like to resize this picture in this cell. How can I do this?

This is the code where I create the column and set the picture in byte array:

```
// player picture column
string propPlayerPicture = "PlayerPicture";
table.Columns.Add(propPlayerPicture, typeof(byte[]));

// set playerPicture, noted that GetPlayerPictureAsync returns a byte array
row[propPlayerPicture] = await GetPlayerPictureAsync(auctionInfo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert the byte array into an `Image` and resize it to a proper size, before setting it to the datagridview cell.

```
int maxwidth = 100;
int maxheight = 100;

//convert to full size image
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)(ic.ConvertFrom(bytearray)); //original size
if (img.Width > maxwidth | img.Height > maxheight) //resize if it is too big
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(maxwidth, maxheight);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bitmap))
        graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, maxwidth, maxheight);
    img = bitmap;
}
```

Then

```
row[propPlayerPicture] = img;
```